# XSLT on client side in IE where XSL contains javascript when XSL document loaded with JQuery

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have a website which frequently uses client side XSLT, some of which contain javascript. The site works only in IE, but I'm trying to make it cross browser.  The XSL documents had been loaded as xml islands, but I changed that to use JQuery instead:

```
function loadIndividualXML(name, src) {
var request = {
    url: src,
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false
    };
window[name]=$.ajax(request).responseXML;
}
```

This works fine on the XSL which doesn't contain javascript, but fails on that which does.  The transform code is:

```
var xmlDomXML = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
xmlDomXML.async = false;
xmlDomXML.load(XMLdata);
var xmlDomResult = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
// xmlDomXSL already loaded with function above
xmlDomXML.transformNodeToObject(xmlDomXSL, xmlDomResult);
```

The error is:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Microsoft JScript runtime error
Object required
line = 1, col = 0 (line is offset from the start of the script block).
Error returned from property or method call.

The beginning of the XSL looks like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
    <xsl:script language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
    var totalRows = 0;
    var rowCount = 0;
    var columnsDesired = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform as the namespace for cross-browser transformation. Use `msxsl:script` instead of `xsl:script` and prepend `script.` before method calls.